# How to get a paired difference between values in the same dataframe column with R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-r -->


    library(reprex)
    set.seed(1)
    Data <- data.frame(
      Y = c(rep("v1",3), rep("v2", 3)),
      X = sample(1:6)
    )
    Data
    #>    Y X
    #> 1 v1 1
    #> 2 v1 4
    #> 3 v1 3
    #> 4 v2 6
    #> 5 v2 2
    #> 6 v2 5

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

And I want to get the paired difference between v1 and v2: 1-6, 4-2, 3-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option would be to `split` the `X` data based on `Y` column and get the difference between the two lists.

```
do.call(mapply, c(split(Data$X, Data$Y), FUN = `-`))
#[1] -5  2 -2
```

If we break down in steps it might be easier to do :

```
tmp <- split(Data$X, Data$Y)
tmp[[1]] - tmp[[2]]
#[1] -5  2 -2
```

---

A `tidyverse` solution would be to get data in wide format and subtract the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(Y) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Y, values_from = X) %>%
  mutate(out = v1 -  v2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#    row    v1    v2   out
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     6    -5
#2     2     4     2     2
#3     3     3     5    -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution. Requires pivotting the table to find the differences:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
    group_by(Y) %>%
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = Y, values_from = X) %>%
    mutate(diff = v1 - v2)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id    v1    v2  diff
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     6    -5
#> 2     2     4     2     2
#> 3     3     3     5    -2
```